# random unwanted '1' appearing in html

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm getting random 1's throughout my html page in chrome.
Can't seem to find this issue on forums or SO.

This is an image of how the page is being rendered:

[image: html after rendering in chrome]

My php file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?= include('head.php') ?>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <?= include('nav.php') ?>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
```

I have no clue what's causing this, can anybody push me in the right direction?

Comment: simple: it's the `=`'s - `<?=` is short hand for "echo" so remove those. I should have posted this as the answer.

Comment: If i remove them the files will not be included

Comment: then change your `<?=` to `<?php` since short tags are not enabled on your system

Comment: I should post my comments to an answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comments:

Simple: it's the `=`'s - `<?=` is short hand for "echo" so remove those.

and change your `<?=` to `<?php` since short tags are not enabled on your system.

The `1`'s are boolean which tell your includes did work/that the file(s) exist.

If it would have failed, then those would have appeared as `0`'s.